# what does struct "sockaddr_in servaddr, clientaddr;" mean?

Tags: c, sockets

`struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cliaddr;`
I am a newbie in socket programing.
What does this statement in socket programing in c mean?
Are we creating a struct named `sockaddr_in` , and are the `servaddr` and `cliaddr` the members? Why is their datatype not mentioned?

Answer (score 4):

> What does this statement in socket programing in c mean?

It declares two uninitialized variables of the type `struct sockaddr_in`.

> Are we creating a struct named `sockaddr_in`?

No. It must be defined already to declare variables, or your program is ill-formed.

> and are the `servaddr` and `cliaddr` the members?

Nope.

> Why is their datatype not mentioned?

It is. See the answer to your first question.

Answer (score 2):

In Unix sockets, header `netinet/in.h` defines a `struct` type `sockaddr_in`, something like this:

```
struct sockaddr_in {
    short            sin_family;   // e.g. AF_INET, AF_INET6
    unsigned short   sin_port;     // e.g. htons(3490)
    struct in_addr   sin_addr;     // see struct in_addr, below
    char             sin_zero[8];  // zero this if you want to
};

struct in_addr {
    unsigned long s_addr;          // load with inet_pton()
};
```

(ref: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/sockaddr_inman.html)

Your `servaddr` and `cliaddr` are names for your sockaddr_in -type structs. Both of them have (in Unix, at least) four members (`short sin_family` etc.). (One of the members is `struct` type `in_addr` called `sin_addr` that is defined couple of lines later having one member `unsigned long s_addr`. There's a reason for a struct with only one member, you can find explanation for that in stackoverflow too.)

If you want to use sockaddr_in you must `#include <netinet/in.h>` or Windows equivalent for `netinet/in.h` (unless you define the struct yourself).